# Get the right Python object according to a setting or user input

Tags: python, inheritance, factory, instantiation

I have two inherited classes in a module shape.py :

```
class Shape(object):

class Triangle(Shape):

class Square(Shape):
```

In my main code I want to instantiate a `Shape` but I don't know what kind of shape it will be. The shape depends on a user input or a setting.

What would be the best way to get the right instance according to a setting or a user input in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with the expected input as key and the class as value (note that there are no `()`):

```
class_dict = {'triangle': Triangle, 'square': Square}

user_input = input()

shape_object = class_dict[user_input]()
```

If the user inputs `triangle`, `shape_object` will be a `Triangle` instance, and if the user inputs `square` then `shape_object` will be a `Square` instance.

Note that this is a basic example, and if the user inputs neither `'triangle'` nor `'square'` then an `KeyError` will be raised.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a design here https://github.com/evandempsey/python-design-patterns/blob/master/patterns/factory.py. They use a `ShapeFactory `. I don't really now what is the best option...

Comment: This is pretty much the same, they simply replace the dictionary in my example with a class with `if` statements. I personally prefer the dictionary. Shorter and cleaner.